# What is the nature of the Terran Dominion?

Tags: video-games, starcraft

I recently started playing Starcraft II, and I remember hearing about the Terran Dominion, and indeed, in the game, you play against them.

My question is, what type of government is the Terran Dominion? I know that they have an Emperor, (Arcturus Mengsk), so their entire planet Korhal reeks of being a monarchy, but I am not sure...

What type of Government is the Terran Dominion?

Answer (score 3):

The [Starcraft Wiki](http://starcraftfanfiction.wikia.com/wiki/Dominion) provides a pretty good description of the government type (absolute monarchy) along with it's oppressive methods of rule.  Some history on it's origins is also provided.

Answer (score 1):

According to wikipedia, its an autocracy with Mengsk as emperor.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Races_of_StarCraft#Terrans)